# Problemas para definir nova rota

Tags: php, cakephp

Não consigo acessar os meus Controllers através da url. Já configurei as rotas, mas pelo que vi, ao invés de chamar o Controller que coloco na url ele está chamando a action

Um Ex:

```
Router::connect('/home/*', array('controller' => 'agendas', 'action' => 'index'));
```

quando acesso **localhost/minha_pasta/home** ele retorna uma mensagem de erro dizendo para criar a action **home**

Ele só acessa esse Controller se colocar a url da seguinte forma **localhost/mina_pasta/index.php/agendas/home**

Comment: Experimente retirar o `/*`. E outra, seu *controller* chama realmente **agenda**? Normalmente usa-se no plural.

Comment: erro de digitação, mas ainda não funcionou. Vou editar a pergunta, para colocar mais alguns detalhes

Comment: Já tive muito esse problema. Felizmente, resolvi ele. Veja a minha resposta

Answer (score 0):

Seu apache (ou sei lá qual servidor você usa) pode não está lendo o seu `.htaccess` ou mesmo nem exista um `.htaccess`

Você disse que ele acessa quando você coloca

`minha_pasta/index.php/controller/ação`

Para funcionar assim:

`minha_pasta/controller/ação`

Você deve definir o seu `.htaccess` dessa forma (na raiz da aplicação)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Se você estiver tendo problemas com a leitura do `htaccess`, poderá alterar o seu `vhosts.conf` e colocar a seguinte instrução:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

Se no caso estiver usando Windows, o trecho onde está `/var/www` deve ser substituído por `C:\\Windows\\xampp\\htdocs`